# Hadwiger number of Erdös-Faber-Lovasz graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings, graph-minors

For any set $X$, let $[X]^2 = \big\{\{a,b\}:a,b \in X, a\neq b\big\}$.

We call a finite, simple, undirected graph $G=(V,E)$ an $n$-*Erdös-Faber-Lovasz (EFL-) graph* if there are $n$ subsets $S_1,\ldots, S_n$ of $V$ such that

1. each $S_k$ has $n$ elements for $k\in\{1,\ldots, n\}$,
2. $|S_k\cap S_j|\leq 1$ for $k\neq j\in \{1,\ldots, n\}$, and
3. $V = \bigcup_{k=1}^n S_k$, and $E = \bigcup_{k=1}^n [S_k]^2$.

The [Erdos-Faber-Lovasz conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Faber%E2%80%93Lov%C3%A1sz_conjecture) says that if $G$ is an $n$-EFL-graph, then $\chi(G) \le n$.

Given any finite, simple, undirected graph $G=(V,E)$, the *Hadwiger number* $\eta(G)$ is the maximum $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $K_n$ is a [minor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_minor) of $G$.

**Question.** Is there $C\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, if $G$ is an $n$-EFL-graph, then $\eta(G) \leq Cn$?

Comment: I cannot follow your "Note". Hadwiger's conjecture asserts that $\chi(G)\leq \eta(G)$. The section "History and partial results" of the wikipedia article you link to mentions a result of [Chang and Lawler](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02126801) according to which $\chi(G)\leq \tfrac{3}{2}\eta(G)-2$. Both results provide lower bounds for $\eta(G)$, but the question asks for an upper bound.

Comment: @PhilippLampe You are right, I will remove the note (= last sentence in the post)